# Replication slave re-reading WAL on restart

Tags: postgresql, replication

I have a standard streaming replication setup going with PostgreSQL 9.1. It works fine. However, if I stop the slave cleanly (to move it or perform other maintenance) and restart it a short time later, it insists on re-reading all the WAL files it has generated before connecting to the master, which is a lot of them and takes hours. I would expect it instead to have noted the last WAL position it got from the master and restart from there.

I feel like I'm missing something here. Is this expected behavior?

My slave's config has the usual suspects:

```
listen_addresses = '*'  
wal_level = hot_standby  
max_wal_senders = 10  
wal_keep_segments = 24  
hot_standby = on
```

Comment: _The standby server will also attempt to restore any WAL found in the standby cluster's pg_xlog directory. That typically happens after a server restart, when the standby replays again WAL that was streamed from the master before the restart, but you can also manually copy files to pg_xlog at any time to have them replayed._ (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/warm-standby.html#STANDBY-SERVER-OPERATION)

Comment: What are your `checkpoint_timeout` and `checkpoint_segments` on master and slave? Did you know about restartpoints? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/wal-configuration.html